# Keeping text where I want it to be? CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, wrapper

I'm pretty new to using HTML and CSS and have been building a website for my band. I've uploaded the first version of the site to the net and have been experiencing problems with the text on the "Bio" page when viewing in resolutions lower than 1440x900. Originally the whole site looked weird at lower resolutions but since I added a wrapper it stopped that for everything except the text on the bio page.

When I was creating the site I used the `<pre>` tag to add the text and I wonder if this is part of my problem? does anyone know how I can rectify this problem? The text is supposed to go to the right of the images.

The website is www.wealmostwere.com

Any tips or hints are most appreciated :)

Many thanks!!

Jay

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
position: relative;
width: 100%;
```

to #biotext

This will solve your problem..

When you give an element a width of 100% in CSS, you’re makeing this element’s content area exactly equal to the explicit width of its parent — but only if its parent has an explicit width..

Comment: That's great thanks a lot :D it has improved the page a lot at lower resolution. Now the only issue is that the text isn't quite vertically aligned with the images at lower resolutions. Do i need to use a similar code for the height? Cheers